# Compute values in DateFormatter (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, date-formatting

I need to convert a date to this format `dd/MM/yyy^xxx` where `xxx = hh * 60 + mm`, For example `31 Aug 2020 02:30AM` in my format will be `31/08/2020^150`, this format is used in communication with the server. I tried

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy^hh*60+mm"
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

but the computation does not work, What is missing?

Comment: `DateFormatter` does not do computation, you need to do the computation yourself.

Comment: @Sweeper I added an example, I think there might be some special characters to be used in dateFormat to allow computation, but I did not find them

Comment: It seems like `xxx` is the minute-of-day, isn't it?

Comment: @Sweeper That's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DateComponents and DateComponentsFormatter to get the number of minutes

```
let date = Date()

let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute], from: date)

let compFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
compFormatter.allowedUnits = [.minute]

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy^"

let string = formatter.string(from: date) + compFormatter.string(for: components)!
```